# Creating a grid layout with one square being scrollable?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Trying to create the following layout using the CSS Grid where only the `main` element should be scrollable.

```
  <header>header</header>
  <div>
    <aside></aside>
    <main>
    </main>
  </div>
  <footer>footer</footer>
```

This is a stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-p4nanm?file=index.html,styles.css

And this is the current CSS attempt:

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

header {
  background-color: gold;
}
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  background-color: burlywood;
  overflow: hidden;
}
aside {
  max-width: 10rem;
}
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  overflow: auto;
}
footer {
  background-color: aqua;
}

p {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

main p {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

The "Weird" thing is that if I add:

```
  overflow: auto;
```

To the `aside` element CSS rule, then both the `aside` and the `main` element will scroll, and work the way I would expect.

But if the `overflow: auto;` rule is removed from the `aside` then most of the content within the `main` element goes away and it also does not scroll.

How can we make it so that only the `main` element scrolls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution will be set to `aside { min-height: 0; }`, because by default it has `auto` and does not shrink from it. Or any `overflow` value other than `visible`.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

header {
  background-color: gold;
}

div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  background-color: burlywood;
  overflow: hidden;
}

aside {
  max-width: 10rem;
  min-height: 0; /*  */
  /* overflow: hidden; */ /* ❗ this will work too */
}

main {
  display: grid;
  overflow: auto;
}

footer {
  background-color: aqua;
}

p {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

main p {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<div>
  <aside>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
     praesentium autem ex nesciunt distinctio earum. Vel, voluptate ratione
     illum, placeat quam ullam, debitis iure exercitationem reprehenderit
     dignissimos corporis. Distinctio, deleniti?
    </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
     praesentium autem ex nesciunt distinctio earum. Vel, voluptate ratione
     illum, placeat quam ullam, debitis iure exercitationem reprehenderit
     dignissimos corporis. Distinctio, deleniti?
    </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
     praesentium autem ex nesciunt distinctio earum. Vel, voluptate ratione
     illum, placeat quam ullam, debitis iure exercitationem reprehenderit
     dignissimos corporis. Distinctio, deleniti?
    </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
     praesentium autem ex nesciunt distinctio earum. Vel, voluptate ratione
     illum, placeat quam ullam, debitis iure exercitationem reprehenderit
     dignissimos corporis. Distinctio, deleniti?
    </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
     praesentium autem ex nesciunt distinctio earum. Vel, voluptate ratione
     illum, placeat quam ullam, debitis iure exercitationem reprehenderit
     dignissimos corporis. Distinctio, deleniti?
    </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
     praesentium autem ex nesciunt distinctio earum. Vel, voluptate ratione
     illum, placeat quam ullam, debitis iure exercitationem reprehenderit
     dignissimos corporis. Distinctio, deleniti?
    </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
     praesentium autem ex nesciunt distinctio earum. Vel, voluptate ratione
     illum, placeat quam ullam, debitis iure exercitationem reprehenderit
     dignissimos corporis. Distinctio, deleniti?
    </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
     praesentium autem ex nesciunt distinctio earum. Vel, voluptate ratione
     illum, placeat quam ullam, debitis iure exercitationem reprehenderit
     dignissimos corporis. Distinctio, deleniti?
    </p>
  </aside>
  <main>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
     praesentium autem ex nesciunt distinctio earum. Vel, voluptate ratione
     illum, placeat quam ullam, debitis iure exercitationem reprehenderit
     dignissimos corporis. Distinctio, deleniti?
    </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
     praesentium autem ex nesciunt distinctio earum. Vel, voluptate ratione
     illum, placeat quam ullam, debitis iure exercitationem reprehenderit
     dignissimos corporis. Distinctio, deleniti?
    </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
     praesentium autem ex nesciunt distinctio earum. Vel, voluptate ratione
     illum, placeat quam ullam, debitis iure exercitationem reprehenderit
     dignissimos corporis. Distinctio, deleniti?
    </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
     praesentium autem ex nesciunt distinctio earum. Vel, voluptate ratione
     illum, placeat quam ullam, debitis iure exercitationem reprehenderit
     dignissimos corporis. Distinctio, deleniti?
    </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
     praesentium autem ex nesciunt distinctio earum. Vel, voluptate ratione
     illum, placeat quam ullam, debitis iure exercitationem reprehenderit
     dignissimos corporis. Distinctio, deleniti?
    </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
     praesentium autem ex nesciunt distinctio earum. Vel, voluptate ratione
     illum, placeat quam ullam, debitis iure exercitationem reprehenderit
     dignissimos corporis. Distinctio, deleniti?
    </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
     praesentium autem ex nesciunt distinctio earum. Vel, voluptate ratione
     illum, placeat quam ullam, debitis iure exercitationem reprehenderit
     dignissimos corporis. Distinctio, deleniti?
    </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
     praesentium autem ex nesciunt distinctio earum. Vel, voluptate ratione
     illum, placeat quam ullam, debitis iure exercitationem reprehenderit
     dignissimos corporis. Distinctio, deleniti?
    </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
     praesentium autem ex nesciunt distinctio earum. Vel, voluptate ratione
     illum, placeat quam ullam, debitis iure exercitationem reprehenderit
     dignissimos corporis. Distinctio, deleniti?
    </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
     praesentium autem ex nesciunt distinctio earum. Vel, voluptate ratione
     illum, placeat quam ullam, debitis iure exercitationem reprehenderit
     dignissimos corporis. Distinctio, deleniti?
    </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
     praesentium autem ex nesciunt distinctio earum. Vel, voluptate ratione
     illum, placeat quam ullam, debitis iure exercitationem reprehenderit
     dignissimos corporis. Distinctio, deleniti?
    </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
     praesentium autem ex nesciunt distinctio earum. Vel, voluptate ratione
     illum, placeat quam ullam, debitis iure exercitationem reprehenderit
     dignissimos corporis. Distinctio, deleniti?
    </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
     praesentium autem ex nesciunt distinctio earum. Vel, voluptate ratione
     illum, placeat quam ullam, debitis iure exercitationem reprehenderit
     dignissimos corporis. Distinctio, deleniti?
    </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
     praesentium autem ex nesciunt distinctio earum. Vel, voluptate ratione
     illum, placeat quam ullam, debitis iure exercitationem reprehenderit
     dignissimos corporis. Distinctio, deleniti?
    </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
     praesentium autem ex nesciunt distinctio earum. Vel, voluptate ratione
     illum, placeat quam ullam, debitis iure exercitationem reprehenderit
     dignissimos corporis. Distinctio, deleniti?
    </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
     praesentium autem ex nesciunt distinctio earum. Vel, voluptate ratione
     illum, placeat quam ullam, debitis iure exercitationem reprehenderit
     dignissimos corporis. Distinctio, deleniti?
    </p>
  </main>
</div>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: Oh - I see now - The `div` has to have `overflow:hidden` ... which I thought I had ... But I just realized that I had multiple tabs open with the same stackblitz ... and I think somehow they pollute each other ... So I think it actually works right in the question too ... Just in case anyone is puzzled looking at it ... :)